# Controller Extension - Report Data Tables

Tags: visualforce, pdf, controller-extension

What is the correct way to declare and reference a report data table (in Visualforce)?

The report is filtered by account, and I want it to be visible when rendered as "pdf".

I'm writing a controller extension to get tasks and events from a contact (the standard controller = Account).  This part works. Now I'm trying to create a data table so I can access report information when I render the report as a pdf.

I used the documentation around "Get Report Data" from the SF developer website, but I'm not sure how to declare it so I can use it in my visualforce page.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_data.htm.

I've tried using

```
Public transient Reports.ReportResults reportResults;
```

in the controller, and then

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportResults.factMap['T!T']}" var="Report">
```

in the VF Page, but it gives me a syntax error.  Found 'reportresults.FactMap'.

This is my first attempt at this, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Is there perhaps a better way to reference a report table that is visible in a pdf rendered VF page?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic problems.

First, you need to use `{ get; set; }` in order to access anything via merge fields.

Second, you can't generally use these types of objects in merge fields, because there are methods involved. Instead, you'll need a "wrapper class" to hold the data, which you'll then expose on the page.

---

```
public class ReportData {
    public Decimal grandTotal { get; set; }
    // ... other properties here ... //
}
public ReportData data { get; set; }
void buildReportData() {
    data = new ReportData();
    Reports.ReportResults results = getReportResults();
    data.grandTotal = (Decimal)results.getFactMap().get('T!T');
    // ... more logic here ... //
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll implement this today and let you know how I get on :)